# Jasmine test for Angular directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm attempting to run a very basic test of an Angular directive, but cannot seem to get it to run. My code is below. The error I'm seeing from jshint is: `'inject' is not defined`, and the error for my failed test is: `TypeError: object is not a function`.

```
'use strict';

describe('playerInfo directive', function() {
  var $compile;
  var $rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('gameApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  it('should replace the element with the appropriate content', function() {
    var element = $compile('<dm-player-info></dm-player-info>')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(element.html()).toContain('Member Since:');
  });
});
```

The test is failing with the above error message as soon as it hits `module`. So clearly the test is not picking up that `angular-mocks` is included. However, I've both referenced it in my `index.html` and tested both with `ngMock` as an app dependency (which crashes my whole app but still doesn't run the test) and without.

UPDATE: I'm currently using jasmine-node for testing. This may be the issue, the need to add jasmine.

Comment: did you include angular-mocks.js?

Comment: I did. Although when I add `ngMock` as a dependency in my app module the entire app stops running (blank page, no errors in console).

Comment: The order you include things in your spec file is important as well. Did you include `angular-mocks` before you included the test js file?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem just now and this is what made my day (in the very end of it actually). Just add `module('ng')` along with `module('yourAppModule')`. I put them before beforeEach block. It should work.